# SSR in 100% Dynamic Multi Tenant VueJS/.NetCore App (Content, Components etc.)

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vue-component, server-side-rendering

I have an existing multi tenant app based on a .Net Core app which we use for base pages – Index page holds the Vue entry point and renders CMS content from a database. This also acts as an API. The front end is primarily VueJS. This is in production and works fine currently.

This is the flow

1. Create core components in an editor and save in a database
2. Create tenants and tenant specific components and core components can be assigned to the tenant at this stage.
3. Each tenant has a CMS where pure html, scripts and Vue components can be used.
4. When saving content or components we parse the content and gather a list of components and dependant components to create page specific minified .js file which we then save to a CDN and reference in the .net core page before initialising Vue.

We do not use an build agents like Webpack etc. for Vue.

We are pivoting slightly from our original requirements and need to support server side rendering, all very straight forward for 99% of projects out there but I’m really struggling with how to apply this to our application as it stands.

Pages, components and scripts are all referenced and updateable at runtime, the core Vue logic has no idea of any components or where they might be referenced/used.

Does anybody have anything similar or any ideas on how we might achieve SSR? I’m open to all suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I've been trying to solve this exact same problem myself. I've debated re-writing my Vue.js components as Blazor components since Blazor's  WebAssembly mode supports pre-rendering now.

Comment: Unfortunately not, please do share if you come up with a way round this

Comment: I have found a solution using Next.js (React) that works well. I think it may be possible with Nuxt.js too. Here's a simple illustration:

https://github.com/leerob/nextjs-multiple-domains.

This strategy would eliminate the need for .net core for page routing but you could keep it for your APIs.